# Error when checking for empty list element

Tags: errors, xifthen, ifthenelse

When I run this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\Entry}[6][\textwidth-3cm-16pt]{        %% new entry
\parbox[t]{#1}{%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#3}{}           }{}{\textbf{#3}}%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#4}{}           }{}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\headdelimiter}{#4}}
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#5}{}           }{}{\hfill\slshape#5\upshape\hspace{-7mm}}%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#5}{}\OR\equal{#6}{}            }{}{\hspace{-7mm}\\[-3.0mm]{\color{colI!20}\rule[2pt]{#1}{0.5pt}}\vspace{-6.0mm}}%
    \ifblank{#6}                        {}{
        \begin{itemize}
            #6
        \end{itemize}
    }
}
}

\begin{document}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}{
    \item asdf
}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}{}

\end{document}
```

I get the error

> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 26

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that `\item` appears in the 5th argument, which is not meant, actually it is meant for the 6th argument, thereby a stray `\item` outside of list occurs.

I prefer `etoolbox` rather than `ifthen` and checking with `\ifblank` whether the argument is empty, or not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcommand{\Entry}[6]{%
  \ifblank{#5}{}{#5}
  \ifblank{#6}{}{%
    \begin{itemize}
      #6
    \end{itemize}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}{}{%
\item asdf
}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}{}{}

\end{document}
```

**A variant with optional arguments**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\Entry}{+m+m+m+m+o+d<>}{%
  \IfValueT{#5}{#5}
  \IfValueT{#6}{%
    \begin{itemize}
      #6
    \end{itemize}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}<%
\item asdf
>

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}[E]<\item And now for something completely different>

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think by trying to make the MWE even more minimal I made some mistakes. I updated the MWE.

Comment: @Make42: Yes, that means totally screwing up my answer ... :-(

Comment: Sorry for that! However, I am not sure that your answer got completely screwed up. I did not mix up the parameter positions, but otherwise the error stays the same. Using `\ifblank` does not work, but I don't see why it should have before if it does not now. The issue is still with `#6` and how to deal with `\item` when asking for `equal`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\Entry}[6][\textwidth-3cm-16pt]{
\parbox[t]{3cm}{#2}%
\parbox[t]{#1}{%
    \ifx#5\relax\else\hfill\slshape#5\upshape\hspace{-7mm}\fi%
    \ifx#6\relax\else
        \begin{itemize}
            #6
        \end{itemize}
    \fi
    }
}
\begin{document}
\Entry{D}{A}{B}{}{
\item asdf
}

\Entry{D}{A}{B}{C}{}
\end{document}
```